# Sync displays using current time

Tags: javascript, time

I'm making a digital signage system and I'd like to sync the displays so that they all show the same screen at the same time. I'm thinking that the simplest way of doing this is using the current time as a marker - all the machines running the displays will have the accurate time, and the amount of slides they have will be the same.

Is there a calculation I could perform on the current time to work out which slide to display which could be used on each screen, with a slide display time of 30 seconds for example?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for the modulo operation…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Bergi's suggestion of using Modulo, I've found a solution. Here is my Javascript code that changes the screen/slide every 30 seconds:

```
var sec = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
var nearest30Sec = Math.round(sec / 30);

var currentSlide = ((nearest30Sec - 1) % 10) + 1;
```

`currentSlide` will produce a number between 1 and 10, which will change every 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience working with this. 
But speaking with a colleague whom has, he pointed me in the direction of Synchroscope.
Seems like the right way to approach it?

Hope it helps!

[Synchroscope Guide](http://me.dt.in.th/page/Synchroscope/)